# Стоит ли использовать магические методы PHP

Tags: php, ооп

Добрый день Stackoverflow!

Сейчас изучаю ООП в PHP по книге Зандстра. М - Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования и остановился на главе "Магические методы"

После прочтения главы у меня возник, возможно, очень странный вопрос, а стоит ли использовать их в своих проектах? Мне показалось, что они сильно запутаны и лучше использовать стандартные getter'ы и setter'ы

Подскажите, где и при каких обстоятельствах стоит использовать магические методы в ООП, если можно с небольшим примером и пояснением

Спасибо!
Всем добра!

Comment: если у вас перечень полей для которых вы хотите определить геттеры/сеттеры известен, то смысла в магических методах в данном контексте нет. Если же вы хотите определить доступ к свойствам произвольной модели, где вы не знаете сколько этих свойств и их имена, вот тут и пригодится вам магия.

Comment: @teran, подскажите, правильно понял или нет, к примеру у меня есть класс Book в свойствах которого я определил несколько свойств, автор, название книги, цена, а через __set() можно дополнительно добавить, что это коллекционное издание, но так как в классе Book я не предусмотрел наличия свойства edition  магический метод $book->edition = 'Коллекционное издание' его добавит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стоит, но только при надобности, а не просто, чтобы использовать.

Например __construct() используется повсеместно.

Если вам нужно сделать что-либо до сериализации или после нее с объектом - используются __sleep() и __wakeup(), чтобы не вызывать методы руками.

__call() запускается при вызове недоступных методов в контексте объект. Таким образом его можно использовать для выброса исключений, так же как и __callStatic() и т д.